# Why is there a marked grave?

Tags: continuity, buffy-the-vampire-slayer

At the end of Buffy the Vampire season five, which was also the ending of the WB run of the series,

> Buffy dies.

The episode concludes with a shot of the clearly-marked grave.

When the show returns in season six, several Buffy-verse months later, we find that the gang has cleverly

> re-purposed Spike's Buffybot to fool Sunnydale's vampires and demons into thinking there was still a slayer in town to maintain order.  It was even hinted that Buffybot was used to fool Buffy's father on the telephone.

If this was the gang's strategy, why did they leave a marked grave in the cemetery?  Since Sunnydale gets unusually high cemetery traffic, wouldn't the lie have been exposed very quickly?

I know that season five was originally intended to be the last  of the series, but UPN had already picked up the series to be continued in the fall of that same year.  The same writers and producers stayed on for the UPN seasons, so I have a hard time assuming this is an unavoidable plot-hole resulting from the series' being resurrected well after cancellation.  At the very least, the gang would have had the headstone removed by the beginning of season six (but we see the headstone is still in place when they go there to perform a ritual).

Is there another plausible explanation?

Comment: FWIW, it doesn't seem to be in a cemetery but rather in a secluded part of the forest. There are no other graves around it.

Comment: @Walt I definitely agree it looks like that (+1) but please see my comment to Paulie_D's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

From all apppearances her grave wasn't in the cemetary at all but rather in a secluded woodland area.

The [wikia](http://buffy.wikia.com/wiki/Buffy_Summers) refers to it as:

> She was buried on the outskirts of Sunnydale

...but I can't find anything official on this.

Images from the resurrection don't show any other graves or headstones in the immediate vicinity.

[image]

Comment: I think this is probably the best possibility, yet this initial shot (https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/ba/bc/df/babcdfb402faff5ca8627bb834495f5b.jpg) of the grave indicates the area is populated enough for landscaping, and possibly a structure, street, or walkway in the background.  Also, in Bargaining Part 1, Buffybot leads the demon gang from the main part of town to the grave in a matter of minutes (if not seconds) when seeking help from Willow because she's broken.